# Can anyone teach a new player to play Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, new-players, new-gm

I have the core book and the Bestiary 2. My brother gave them to me but I've never found time to sit and learn how to play by myself.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Sadly, this question is not likely to remain open as it is too broad in its scope (see the [faq](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/faq)). I suggest you read the books, learn the system and then post any specific questions you have here.

Comment: Welcome.  Read the core book and then check out questions with the [tag:new-players] tag, especially the linked question. Then feel free and ask specific questions you have! Also feel free and join us in chat (if someone else would be so kind as to vote up your question so you'll have the 10 rep required).

Comment: First read the book. If you can't find time to read the book, you will be disappointed to find out that playing it takes even *more* time.

Comment: Easy. The answer is 'yes' :-)